# filter map vs list comprehension

Tags: python

Is filter/map equivalent to list comprehension?
Suppose I have the following function

```
def fib_gen():
    a,b = 0,1
    yield 0
    yield 1
    while True:
        a,b = b,a+b
        yield b
```

Now I can use list comprehension to list fib numbers:

```
a = fib_gen()
print [a.next() for i in range(int(sys.argv[1]))]
```

Suppose I want to list only even fib numbers. I would do the following with filter/map:

```
a = fib_gen()
print filter(even, map(lambda x: a.next(), range(int(sys.argv[1]))))
```

How can I get the same result with list comprehension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a generator to store the intermediate result, and "filter" on it.

```
fibs = (a.next() for i in whatever)
even_fibs = [num for num in fibs if num % 2 == 0]
```

or in one line:

```
even_fibs = [num for num in (a.next() for i in whatever) if num % 2 == 0]
```

Note that, if you want to take a definite number of elements from an iterator, you could use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead:

```
from itertools import islice
fibs_max_count = int(sys.argv[1])
even_fibs = [num for num in islice(fib_gen(), fibs_max_count) if num%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 13):

> Is filter/map equivalent to list comprehension?

Yes, `map(f, L)` is equivalent to `[f(x) for x in L]`. `filter(f, L)` is equivalent to `[x for x in L if f(x)]`. But, since list comprehensions with side effects are generally bad (and here you modify the state of the generator), you can use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) for a bit cleaner solution:

```
 a = fib_gen()
 a = itertools.islice(a, int(sys.argv[1]))
 a = itertools.ifilter(even, a)
 print list(a)
```

Answer (score 7):

`filter` and `map` converts quite easily into a list comprehension.

Here's a basic example:

```
[hex(n) for n in range(0, 100) if n > 20]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
list(map(hex, filter(lambda x: x > 20, range(0, 100))))
```

The comprehension is in my opinion more readable. However if the conditions become very advanced, I prefer `filter`.

So in your case:

```
[n for n in itertools.islice(fib_gen(), 100) if even(n)]
```

I have used `islice` here because the sequence is infinite. But if you use a generator expression it becomes an infinite stream as well:

```
gen = (n for n in fib_gen() if even(n))
```

Now you can slice the sequence as well with `islice`:

```
print itertools.islice(gen, int(sys.argv[1]))
```

This avoids the need to use `next` in the comprehensions themselves. As long as you don't try to evaluate the infinite sequence (as we would if we omitted `islice` in the list comprehension), we can work with your sequence.

Comment: Thanks. What about filtering expressions containing next() as in my example?

Comment: @Oleg: Oh, I'm adding some info, check my latest addition and you'll see you can avoid `next` too.

Comment: Your hex/range example is not a traditional filter map. A filter map can filter on the result of the mapped procedure, not just on the input to that expression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing this is going to work with a generator. In order to have this work with list comprehension, you would need to have:

```
print [a.next() for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])) if even(a.next())]
```

This returns:

```
[1, 3, 13, 55, 233]
```

The problem is you need to access twice the next number in the list but the second a.next() call makes what it supposed to do, ie get the next number. To my knowledge, it is not possible to store the value of a.next() with list comprehension to use twice.

Comment: it is possible but you have to nest as in `print [n for n,i in ( (a.next(),i) for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])) ) if even(n)]`, `n` is `a.next()` and is used twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
a = fib_gen()
print [a.next() for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])) if i%3==0]
```

This is a particular case that works because every third fibbonacci number is even.

Answer (score 0):

You can always generate the even fibo numbers only too...

```
def evenfib():
    """ Generates the even fibonacci numbers """
    a, b = 2, 0
    while True:
        a, b = b, a+4*b
        yield a
```